# How to configure Hibernate file with variables

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to build my java app using Maven, and deploy it on tomcat.  I want to use variables for my username and password for hibernate. I currently have hibernate.cfg.xml and there I set the username blablabla
like this. How can I change it to take ${hibernate_username}?

Answer (score 0):

**Example of *hibernate.cfg.xml* file with variables**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">${hibernate_username}</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">${hibernate_password}</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://${hibernate_db_host}/${hibernate_db_name}</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate_show_sql}</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Yep, when I run my app on tomcat server, it doesn't connect to DB.

Comment: Hey @StudentBobr Can you update the exception/error message which you are getting during into your question, so that exact issues can be identified

Comment: there is no error it's just not working. I guess there should be some settings regarding one of the patterns in pom.xml file.

Comment: follow this simple example step by step : https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/webmvc/spring5-mvc-hibernate5-example/